# Apache server disallow php open of files in upper directories

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I have server seciurity problem. Problem is virus that spreads from one of weakly programmed sites on server. directory structure is as follows (DirectAdmin):
domains

```
-domain1.com
--public_html
-domain2.com
--public_html
-domain3.com
--public_html
-domain4.com
--public_html
```

What I'm looking for:
Long time ago i head something about possibility of blocking inclusion of files from upper dirs (can't find it, since dont know how it's called).

What I want is to block possiblity to open files in PHP when:
Script is called from public_html/index.php

- I want it to be able to fopen/file_get_contents/require/include files that are in public_html and subdirectories
- I also want to block possibiliy to access files that are are in parent directories of public_html

Problem is caused because server administrator uses same user to own ftp files as to execute them with apache. Virus spreads since I cannot deny "write" to those files.

Comment: it is called open_basedir in PHP

Comment: gonna try that if it works. hope it can't be overwritten by ini_set? or can it? (or dependable by server config?)

Comment: It does not work. .haccess, php.ini nor ini_set allow me to block inclusion. Do not have access to apache configfiles.